# Sharepoint 2010 Authentication Error status 401

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication

We have application created in ***Ipad*** to display all images from Sharepoint to Ipad.

It is working well for small amount of Images. Display around 200 to 500 images without authentication fails. We face problem when there are lots of images. For some images (if images in large  amount) it returns status "401" Unauthorized and then never request again for authentication.

To authenticate in Ipad we use Authentication challenge to create authentication for each image . For small amount of images there are no problem. When images are more then 1000 then for some images it returns 401.

Is there any ways in Ipad to Authenticate at only once and then it able to load all images ?

Any Help would be very much helpful

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean LDAP instead of LPAD?

Comment: Have you got any solution? I have a same problem :)